# How convert handlebars param from string to integer in partial?

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

I'm calling a partial with `{{> my-partial width="1200" }}` so, in that partial I need to use the `width` param in order to do arithmetical operations like `{{divide (toInt width) 2}}` (to obtain **600**) but I get the following error in `divide` helper:

> (node:5185) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: expected the first argument to be a number

I'm using gulp with assemble, as well, I'm using the **math** and **number** handlebars helpers.

Any suggestion how can I deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own helper.
Go To app.js (or what ever the application entry point) and add the following lines:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerHelper('_toInt', function(str) {
  return parseInt(str,10);
});
```